# FCM not sending message to iOS nativescript

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, angular2-nativescript

I have used the native script push plugin to register for notifications.

```
pushPlugin.register(iosSettings, (apnstoken: String) => {
            console.log("Device registered. Access token: " + apnstoken);
            setString("apnsToken", apnstoken.toString());
            this.api.getFCMToken(apnstoken);
            if(iosSettings.interactiveSettings) {
                pushPlugin.registerUserNotificationSettings(() => {
                    console.log('Successfully registered for interactive push.');
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log('Error registering for interactive push: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                });
            }
        }, (errorMessage: any) => {
            console.log("Device NOT registered! " + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
        });
```

So everything goes fine. I register my device, get an APNs token, use APNs token and get FCM token using Google http protocol. I used a third party app called "Easy APNs Provider" for Mac to test the notification directly to APNs token and I receive the notification just fine even when the app is terminated.

The problem is here. I have configured the FCM with the right bundle identifier, correct SSL certificated that I got from my Apple developer account. But trying to send from Firebase Console is never received. Even though the console says "Completed", the Sent count is 0.

I am lost because APNs token works fine from a different tool. I did get the FCM token using the same APNs token. But GCM does not send the notification even though it has the same certificate.

Thanks in Advance,
Jony

Comment: Have you uploaded your authentication key? Is method swizzling enabled? Try sending a message just to the device's FCM token, which you get from the `didReceiveRegistrationToken` method. Check out Todd's blog post for lots of good advice on debugging: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html

Comment: I uploaded the authentication key. But I do not know what swizzling enabled means? Where do I do that? I did try sending a message to the device's FCM token. Nothing happened.